# Saving nested list elements as .rds

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am trying to save multiple list elements into separate rds files. `BC.Results` is a list containing 10,000 list elements. I only need the first list element: `BC.Results[[Groups]][[Business.Cycles]][[1]]`.

I index by i Groups and j Business.Cycles. Unfortunately, the for loop I created isn't pasting the correct names nor is it iterating. Instead it returns *NA*.

```
Business.Cycles <- c("Expansions", "Recessions")
Groups <- c( "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Unconditional")

for (i in unique(Groups)) {
  for (j in unique(Business.Cycles)) {
    saveRDS(BC.Results[[i]][[j]][[1]],file = paste0('Results/03_', Groups[i],'_',Business.Cycles[j],'.rds'),compress=TRUE)
  }
}
```

The data is large but i have included two list elements as an example:

**List element 1:**

```
dput(BC.Results$Unconditional$Expansions[[1]])
list(nij = structure(c(36L, 42L, 13L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 314L, 
146L, 51L, 17L, 5L, 1L, 25L, 135L, 269L, 147L, 46L, 13L, 0L, 
5L, 68L, 142L, 162L, 87L, 32L, 4L, 1L, 28L, 51L, 84L, 89L, 42L, 
14L, 0L, 10L, 12L, 37L, 46L, 48L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 11L, 17L, 
13L), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", 
"Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", 
"B", "Caa")), class = "table"), ni = c(Aaa = 106, Aa = 597, A = 635, 
Baa = 486, Ba = 296, B = 157, Caa = 48), pij = structure(c(0.339622641509434, 
0.0703517587939698, 0.0204724409448819, 0.00411522633744856, 
0, 0, 0, 0.367924528301887, 0.525963149078727, 0.22992125984252, 
0.104938271604938, 0.0574324324324324, 0.0318471337579618, 0.0208333333333333, 
0.235849056603774, 0.226130653266332, 0.423622047244094, 0.302469135802469, 
0.155405405405405, 0.0828025477707006, 0, 0.0471698113207547, 
0.113902847571189, 0.223622047244094, 0.333333333333333, 0.293918918918919, 
0.203821656050955, 0.0833333333333333, 0.00943396226415094, 0.0469011725293132, 
0.0803149606299213, 0.172839506172839, 0.300675675675676, 0.267515923566879, 
0.291666666666667, 0, 0.016750418760469, 0.0188976377952756, 
0.0761316872427984, 0.155405405405405, 0.305732484076433, 0.333333333333333, 
0, 0, 0.0031496062992126, 0.00617283950617284, 0.0371621621621622, 
0.10828025477707, 0.270833333333333), class = "table", .Dim = c(7L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", 
"Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"))), pj = c(Aaa = 0.04, 
Aa = 0.246451612903226, A = 0.273118279569892, Baa = 0.21505376344086, 
Ba = 0.132903225806452, B = 0.0726881720430108, Caa = 0.0197849462365591
), se.pij = structure(c(0.0459982672852076, 0.0104666967129724, 
0.00561961134456826, 0.00290391081896931, 0, 0, 0, 0.0468393551040512, 
0.0204360306376829, 0.0166982234952571, 0.0139019368900625, 0.013523496586438, 
0.0140138452533828, 0.0206151772344408, 0.0412338337793178, 0.0171208915119397, 
0.019609029268951, 0.0208355089081026, 0.021057720335553, 0.0219939606437451, 
0, 0.0205914481746989, 0.013002318366035, 0.0165351083051226, 
0.0213833433033195, 0.0264786112064143, 0.032149965931533, 0.0398927961565141, 
0.00938935699174292, 0.00865313844408357, 0.0107852675638354, 
0.0171513482702433, 0.026652785827002, 0.0353284095820768, 0.0656057070405944, 
0, 0.00525239711276488, 0.00540348634628996, 0.0120301108369673, 
0.021057720335553, 0.0367692176241696, 0.0680413817439772, 0, 
0, 0.0022235979496149, 0.00355287386097852, 0.0109946448674865, 
0.024799275878385, 0.0641421986177471), class = "table", .Dim = c(7L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", 
"Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"))))
```

**List element 2:**

```
 dput(BC.Results$Large$Recessions[[1]])
list(nij = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(7L, 7L
), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", 
"Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = "table"), 
    ni = c(Aaa = 0, Aa = 0, A = 2, Baa = 3, Ba = 6, B = 6, Caa = 0
    ), pij = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
    0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), class = "table", .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", 
    "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", 
    "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"))), pj = c(Aaa = 0, Aa = 0.294117647058824, 
    A = 0.176470588235294, Baa = 0.235294117647059, Ba = 0.235294117647059, 
    B = 0.0588235294117647, Caa = 0), se.pij = structure(c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.353553390593274, 0.272165526975909, 
    0.152145154862546, 0.152145154862546, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.152145154862546, 
    0.192450089729875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.272165526975909, 0.192450089729875, 
    0.152145154862546, 0, 0, 0, 0.353553390593274, 0, 0.152145154862546, 
    0.192450089729875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.152145154862546, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), class = "table", .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
        i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", 
        "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"))))
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, hard to say without the example data, if possible paste the output of `str(BC.Results)`.

Comment: I've included example data in the original post.

Comment: Why are you using  `Groups[i]` and `Business.Cycles[j]` ? `i` and `j` are not the numbers but  the values inside the vectors you defined. Since your loop is not including sequantial numbers, it is normal having NA with   `Groups[i]` or`Business.Cycles[j]` . Just use `i` and `j` instead of `Groups[i]` and `Business.Cycles[j]`.